# How do I create a 'dynamic' pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a class `unit`, with an element `int holding[4];`

```
void main()
{
    vector<vector<unit> > allunits;
    vector<vector<short> > selectedunits; //This contains certain indexes for the above vector
    allunits.resize(2);
    selectedunits.resize(2);
    allunits[0].resize(5);
    int *ptr = &allunits[0][selectedunits[0][0]].holding[0]; //obviously dysfunctional
}
```

What I would like is to have this pointer change what it points to dynamically. When the value of `selectedunits[0][0]` changes, I want `ptr` to automatically point to the new value of `allunits[0][selectedunits[0][0]].holding[0]`. When `selectedunits[0]` is an empty vector, `ptr` can be anything, but it can't throw a runtime error, which is what it does now.

So, if I later have the code `selectedunits[0].push_back(2);`, I want `ptr` to point to `allunits[0][2].holding[0]`, and then the line `selectedunits[0][0]=1;` ought to make `ptr` point to `allunits[0][1].holding[0]`

Edit: The point of this code: 
This is all for a game. `allunits` is a vector of units, and `selectedunits` stores which units are selected. They are two dimensional since they are both organized into [player][index]. `allunits[0]` holds the units of the first player, and so on.

The pointer is passed to a constructor for an object that prints text to the screen, under certain conditions. The text to be printed is information about the selected unit, and includes whatever number the pointer is pointing to. A different object would print different data, hence the pointer.

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way to do what you're doing.

Comment: Try reformulating the question adding more domain specific information and less code. I agree with David, you are most probably doing it in a suboptimal way.

Comment: Not to sound like an idiot, but what do you mean 'domain specific information'?

Comment: "obviously dysfunctional"... truer words are rarely spoken. You probably have a whiteboard somewhere that explains *why* this layout is necessary, but I can assure you some *very* smart people are looking at that layout via this code-only and scratching their heads until their scalp bleeds.

Comment: @drowdemon domain-specific means give us some ideas on what `A` is supposed to hold (what *kind* of object it represents), likewise with the 2D index table `b`. A general "Class A represents.. blah..; b contains indexes pairs/trios/etc which are lookups into an A for..  blah.. etc." As I said before, some very sharp people on SO and perhaps one may proffer up an idea that you didn't consider that would make this considerably easier.

Comment: @drowdemon there you go. thats better. thanks.

Comment: If you want to compute something that depends on dynamic data, write a function. If you want to package the function and the data together, create an object. Pointers don't do anything like that, they can only point to places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function or class. If you're in C++11, create a lambda locally that binds to the vectors. Otherwise, create a function that takes the vectors as const by-reference arguments, or move the vectors into their own class and put the accessor code in a member function.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to make a new function for every variable that I want to display, as it's a bit tedious. Is there a way to either make a generic function that will work for any variable that is somehow passed in, or avoid functions? I'm not in C++11, so lambda's are out.

Comment: How many variables do you have? Why can't you use a function argument?

Comment: What would the argument be? I can't pass the value I want, since that would be the original dysfunctional pointer.

Comment: I'll accept this, simply because that I did ended up using functions. Thanks for the help everyone!